# Weibull - Table

Tags: probability-distributions, median

I'm very confused with the parameters used with Weibull to calculate the MTBF.

According to my course, we calculate the MTBF using :

**MTBF = A * η + γ**

where γ and η are calculated with a Weibull distribution (an excel sheet does that for me).

However, for the parameter A, I use [this table](http://homeomath2.imingo.net/loistable2.htm), which seems to correspond to the values that are used in my course.

My question is : how are the values in the table calculated ? I cannot understand how I can calculate them manually if I needed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle A=\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{\beta})$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !

Comment: You are welcome! :-)